# Warnsdorff’s algorithm for custom move in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I have written a program to find the list for move required to cover all square of the chessboard using Warnsdorff’s algorithm. it is perfectly working for 7x7 board but not working for board like 8x8, 10x10 or 16x16. Its goes on running for long. The below are the code. Please point out where I am going wrong.

```
object PawnTourMain {

  def main(args: Array[ String ]): Unit = {

    val kt = PawnTour(7)
    kt.findTour(0, 1, 0)
    kt.printSolution        
  }

  class PawnTour(size: Int, board: Array[ Array[ Int ] ], possibleMoves: Array[ Array[ Array[ Point ] ] ]) {

    val UNUSED = -1

    def findTour(x: Int, y: Int, current: Int): Boolean = {
      if (board(x)(y) != UNUSED) return false
      //Mark current position as 'current'
      board(x)(y) = current
      if (current == size * size - 1) { //done :)
        return true
      }
      for (d <- possibleMoves(x)(y)) {
        if (findTour(d.x, d.y, current + 1)) return true
      }
      //if we are here, all our options ran out :(
      //reset the current cell and return false
      board(x)(y) = UNUSED
      false
    }

    def printSolution: Unit = {
      board foreach {
        row =>
          row foreach (number => print(number + " ")); println
      }
    }    
  }

  case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

  object PawnTour {

    val DIRECTIONS = Array(Point(3, 0), Point(-3, 0), Point(2, -2), Point(2, 2), Point(0, 3), Point(0, -3), Point(-2, -2), Point(2, 2))

    def apply(n: Int): PawnTour = {
      val board = Array.fill[ Int ](n, n)(-1)
      val possibleMoves = Array.tabulate(n, n) { (x, y) =>
        DIRECTIONS.flatMap { d =>
          val nx = x + d.x
          val ny = y + d.y
          if ((nx >= 0 && nx < n) && (ny >= 0 && ny < n)) Option(Point(nx, ny)) else None
        }
      }

      var x = 0
      while (x < n) {
        var y = 0
        while (y < n) {
          val moves: Array[ Point ] = possibleMoves(x)(y)
          moves.sortBy((o1: Point) => possibleMoves(o1.x)(o1.y).size)
          y += 1
          println(moves.toList)
        }
        x += 1
      }
      new PawnTour(n, board, possibleMoves)
    }

    def printSolution(array: Array[ Array[ Int ] ]): Unit = {
      array foreach {
        row =>
          row foreach (number => print(number + " ")); println
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JoelBerkeley _" but not working for board like 8x8, 10x10"_ -> most likely not.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley No, because OP specifically asks for a bug fix for 8, 10 and 16 squared. This is a specific programming problem, so on that count it would fit perfectly on SO. However, OP has failed to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoelBerkeley one of the output could be :
output is in 10x10
mcve
 0 57 15  1 58 16  2 59 17  3 
25 41 12 26 42 11 27 43 10 28 
14 69 91 76 70 90 75 99 89 45 
93 56 72 94 86 78 95 60 18  4 
24 40 13 80 74 98 88 44  9 29 
51 68 92 77 71 82 85 64 32 46 
36 55 73 97 87 79 96 61 19  5 
23 39 52 81 84 63 31 83  8 30 
50 67 35 49 66 34 48 65 33 47 
37 54 22 38 53 21  7 62 20  6

run code for 7x7 
Output :
0 36 29 5 35 28 48 
21 16 11 22 17 12 23 
30 6 44 14 9 43 34 
1 37 18 4 40 27 47 
20 15 10 25 45 13 24 
31 7 41 32 8 42 33 
2 38 19 3 39 26 46 

if you run the code for 7x7

Comment: @JoelBerkeley it dose not belong to codereview

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia

> The knight is moved so that it always proceeds to the square from which the knight will have the fewest onward moves

Your implementation does not take into account already visited squares. It creates and sorts possible moves on empty board but forgets to update them when algorithm makes a move.

When square is visited you should remove it from possible moves and then reorder possible moves again

Comment: I am updating 

`board(x)(y) = current`

Comment: I am talking about `possibleMoves` - it is constructed only once for empty board but should be recalculated every time when board is changed